# Change Tax 19% to 0 Based on Eu countries & VAT number Magento2.2

Tags: magento2.2, shipping-tax

Different-2 Tax applied on my website, but I want to change TAX 19% to 0(Zero) for EU countries if customer give us the valid VAT Number,

Product price is configured including TAX, So on the checkout 19% TAX is featuring but not added to Total because price is including tax, i just want to show the TAX=0 there, logic is if country is EU and VAT id is valid then TAX =0.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to enable the Magento core VAT validation at "Stores -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group". Also set "Show VAT Number on Storefront" to "Yes".

But there is more to check, like the tax rules. You can find an example configuration at: https://www.geissweb.de/docs/eu-vat-enhanced-for-magento-2#configuration-manual

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I already done it via Observer

Comment: @Noshad Can you please share your Observer code to remove tax if valid vat id? It will very helpfull to me.

Comment: @Noshad Can you please share the way to do it with an Observer? Thank you

Comment: @JaiminParikh Did you manage to do it with an Observer?